# AR.JS: How Do I Return a Marker Camera's World Position in Arjs?

Tags: augmented-reality, ar.js

I want to return the position of a marker-camera as it moves around in a scene.  I've tried the following AFRAME component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('getworlddir',{
    tick: function(time, timeDelta){
        var worldDir = this.el.object3D.getWorldPosition(); 
        console.log (worldDir) 
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this only returns the world origin position.  My goal is to add a look-at function to follow the Marker-Camera's x and z position
.  Is there a more appropriate way to do this?

David

Comment: Did you find a solution on your own ?

Comment: What do you mean by "only returns the world origin position"? Can you share a working code example?